# Detect Rebuild in Pre/Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to detect a rebuild vs a normal build in the pre/post build event?

I am preparing some files and would like to regenerate them only for a rebuild.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691847/visual-studio-2008-post-build-event-only-run-on-rebuild